# Is it possible querying many-to-many entites without navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework-4

Is it possible to create join query on entites in many to many relations if both sides have no navigation properties in code (ICollection) but association exist?

Maybe somehow trough linq or Entity SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the junction table is part of the entity model you can do something like:

```cs
from a in db.AAntities
join ab in db.ABs // the junction class
     on a.Id equeals ab.IdA
join b in db.BEntitites
     on ab.IdB equals b.Id into bees
select new { A = a, Bees = bees }
```

which will produce a list of A entities with their related B entities.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is it somehow possible without junction class? EF model is aware of association but if I don't expose junction class I can not find a way to access one from another even from EF contex.

Comment: Could you show a (slimmed down) model? Maybe in a new question. I'm not sure which associations you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public partial class User
    {

        public virtual int Id   {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public virtual string Mail  {
            get { }
            set { _}
        }


        public virtual string Password  {
            get { }
            set { ; }
        }
}


 public partial class UserGroupNew
    {

        public virtual int Id   {
            get {  }
            set { }
        }


        public virtual string Name  {
            get {  }
            set { }
        }


        public virtual string Description   {
            get {  }
            set {  }
        }
}
```

and those two entites are in many to many relation. It would be nice if I can have model without navigation properties and manage relationship just trough repository class. Junction class is ok but best option (if possible) would be handling it without extra properties or classes.

Comment: Please convert this to a new question. StackOverlow is not designed for discussions. Answers should be just that: answers.